# My monitor looks way too sharp

Tags: windows-7, display

My Philips 27" monitor started to display too sharp, usually it displayed everything smoother. The cable is connected correctly. Here is my resolution and also you will see what I mean by "too sharp"

[image: desktop screenshot]
[larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9tXp.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps PNG would have been a better choice, all I can see are JPEG artifacts. :D What type of connection are you using?

Comment: The `.jpeg` compressed file is useless due to compression and the resulting artefacts, and if you capture a screenshot it wouldn't take into account how your eye views the monitor, that might be an entirely different story. Define "sharp" and "smoother". If you lower the resolution of your monitor, does that look "smoother" like the way it was before? Your GPU driver settings might also have a word in this.

Comment: The screenshot looks normal to me. Could you check if sharpness is caused by some monitor display settings? In menu of your display, could you select "Reset to Factory Settings"?

Comment: Isn't there a font setting similar to this, something like anti-aliasing maybe?

Comment: @Xen2050 its ClearType ([random how-to page about ClearType](https://www.winhelp.us/change-font-smoothing-in-windows.html)), and it could be a culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot looks normal to me.

1. Check if sharpness is caused by some monitor settings. Use buttons on your monitor to enter menu of your display, then select "Reset to Factory Defaults" (or similar)
2. Check if your graphic adapter has its separate adjustment utility where additional image parameters are set. Reset them to defaults. (You did not mention your graphic adapter type so far.)

If you think there is something sharper than usual on image you posted, then please be more specific. Also try to view the image on different computer before. Added sharpness can be recognized well on text labels, but I can see nothing special on fonts on your screenshot.